# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request): on Angular + NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I have an Angular and NodeJS application with Express (v4.17.1). I expose a REST API like this:

```
app.get('/myRestApi', function (req, res) 
{
  console.log('here you are ... ');
  res.end('success!\n');
});
```

and the `body` of this API contains these parameters:

```
{"name":"Joe",
 "surname":"Soap",
 "coordinate":"ASNDNFNS;SDFGSDFGSDF;ASFRTGERG;SERFQEAWE"}
```

The issue is that when I receive the `coordinate` field larger than a certain amount (so a lot of these `ASFRTGERG;SERFQEAWE`) I get the error on the browser (regardless the browser):

```
The server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request).
```

As I do not get the `console.log('here you are ... ');` log I suppose NodeJS discards it returning 400. I'm pretty sure NodeJS returns this as on the browser I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Length: 0
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Express
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
```

****UPDATE****

I've set the DEBUG level on NodeJS and the request never get to the backend so the problem is in the Angular side I believe. At one point on the Angular side I do this:

```
window.location.href = this.url;   //this.url = /myRestApi
```

which navigates to the `/myRestApi` URL. I believe that `window.location.href` mechanism got a problem here as one field of the body of this request (see above) is too big then it crashes? ... or something that cause 400.

Suggestions?

Comment: When you say "the body of this API..." I assume you mean the body of a POST request? Are you trying to POST data to the `/myRestApi` endpoint? If so, your endpoint as defined is only accepting GET requests. Express is receiving the request just fine as you can see in the `X-Powered-By: Express` header, but you're getting an error because there's no handler for POST.

Comment: good point and I've added the POST method for the same interface but Angular specifically says:

[0] [HPM] GET /myRestApi -> http://[::1]:7892

I've tried again to reduce the size of the 'coordinate' field and indeed work with the GET. I'm wandering if there is something I have to specify when I redirect ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the issue and the problem was that the HTTP GET sent to the backend was too big. After a deeper analysis, I've seen that the cookie made a huge difference in my case.

I've fixed it by increasing the max HTTP header size:

```
node --max-http-header-size 21000 application.js
```